# Do ImageOptimize Volume Variant Transforms replace Craft's default Asset Transforms?

Tags: plugin-imageoptimize

Do the ImageOptimize variants that are set on volumes replace the default image transforms that can be set within Craft asset settings?

I just want to check as the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize) isn't really explicit about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not replace Craft transforms. They are in addition to. And in fact, Image Optimize uses regular old Craft Transforms under the hood.

Image Optimize will do three major things for you:

- Every image transform you do, whether it be via Craft image transforms, or the Optimized Images field will be run through a variety of image optimizers that you have installed, including making `.webp` variants
- An Optimized Images field makes it easy to create an image `srcset` for doing responsive images
- You can entirely replace the transform method from your local server to a service like Imgix or Thumbor

These all operate independent of each other, but they can work together as well.

Comment: Added some further clarification.